# In Multi-core / Multi processor architecture what part of the system synchronizes the processors to work in MIMD mode?

Tags: synchronization, multiprocessing, multicore

When a multi-processor system excecutes instructions (like AMD quad core Opteron) some kind of an on-board device must ensure the syncronization of cores having instruction loads from their respective memory locations.

But what is that device that syncronize the cores?

Is AMD HyperTransport Hub can do that core synchronizatoin?  Can the HyperTransport controller get a flag that a core is idle and make it to fetch a next instruction to run?

Answer (score 1):

Hypertransport is network. The synchronization is done either in the core (some registers for recording transactions, locks, ...) or it is implemented in the memory controller.

see transactional memory http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transactional_memory

Comment: HT is a network, agree.  But the HT has a multiprocessor in it for a reason, I guess.  If I got it right (and I am not sure :-) about that) the HT processor should regulate the traffic or syncronize the devices that use HT.  The HT controller should signal the cores to do transfers somehow.  I just can't find any descriptions of that.